# I can't import a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, import, modulenotfounderror

I want to import a function from a .py file that I have in the same directory.
To import the function, I'm doing this:

```
from file1 import a
```

I need this to work when I run my program on Windows and on Raspbian, but it only works on windows.
When I try to run my program on Raspbian I get this exception:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'

Am I missing something?
Shouldn't it run on Raspbian too?

Comment: What's `file1`? If it's an external library, you'll need to install it.

Comment: File1 is another .py file that I've created, and where the function a is defined